# Loading a resource model in Magento- failed to open file

Tags: php, magento, model-view-controller

I am trying to ues a resource model and get the following when I try to load it:

`Warning: include(Mage\Core\Resource\Model.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 93`

My controller action looks like:

```
$blogpost = Mage::getModel("test/blogpost");
$blogpost->load(1);
```

My `config.xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Lock_Test>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Lock_Test>
  </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <test>
                <class>Lock_Test_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>test_resource</resourceModel>
            </test>
            <test_resource>
                <class>Lock_Test_Model_Resource</class>
            </test_resource>
        </models>
    </global>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <lock_router>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>Lock_Test</module>
          <frontName>test</frontName>
        </args>
      </lock_router>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

I have no idea why it is trying to load from the `Mage` directory. I can't see anything wrong with my config file.

I'm loosly following [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-5-magento-models-and-orm-basics) tutorial, although I haven't created the entities and table name above, I would think it should still find my Resource Model.

Please help!

`app\code\local\Lock\Test\Model\Blogpost.php` look like:

```
<?php
    class Lock_Test_Model_Blogpost extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
    {
        protected function _construct()
        {
            $this->_init("test/blogpost");
        }
    }
```

`app\code\local\Lock\Test\Model\Resource\Blogpost.php` looks like:

```
<?php
    class Lock_Test_Model_Resource_Blogpost extends Mage_Core_Resource_Model
    {
        protected function _construct()
        {
            $this->_init("test/blogpost", "blogpost_id");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with config too. Can you show us your model and resource model?

Comment: Hi. Please see my edit. It only happens when I call the load function!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your resource model

```
class Lock_Test_Model_Resource_Blogpost extends Mage_Core_Resource_Model
```

There is no such class as **Mage_Core_Resource_Model**, that is why Magento tries to find him in Mage\Core\Resource\Model.php. What you want to extend from is probably **Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract**.

Comment: Looks like a promising answer.. I'll give it a try and let you know. Thanks!